# Batch/Shell script to update to text file arguments

Tags: powershell, batch-file, string-interpolation

I have a text file with the contents
**example.txt**

```
My name is {param1}
I live in {param2}
These are all the parameters passed to batch scripts {params}
```

How should i write and Batch/shell script to pass arguments to example.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveat**: Use the following solutions only with input files that you *trust*, because it is possible to embed arbitrary commands inside the text (preventing that is possible, but requires more work):

In a **PowerShell script**, named, say `Expand-Text.ps1`:

```bsh
# Define variables named for the placeholders in the input file,
# bound to the positional arguments passed.
$param1, $param2, $params = $args[0], $args[1], $args

# Read the whole text file as a single string.
$txt = Get-Content -Raw example.txt

# Replace '{...}' with '${...}' and then use
# PowerShell's regular string expansion (interpolation).
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(($txt -replace '\{', '${'))
```

Calling `.\Expand-Text.ps1 a b c` then yields:

```
My name is a
I live in b
These are all the parameters passed to batch scripts a b c
```

---

In a **batch file**, named, say `expandText.cmd`, using PowerShell's CLI:

```
@echo off

:: # \-escape double quotes so they're correctly passed through to PowerShell
set params=%*
set params=%params:"=\"%

:: "# Call PowerShell to perform the expansion.
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -c ^
  "& { $txt = Get-Content -Raw example.txt; $param1, $param2, $params = $args[0], $args[1], $args; $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(($txt -replace '\{', '${')) }" ^
  %params%
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the text file. I am giving a
Code of batch file to create the text file and pass arguments to it.

```
@echo off
echo My name is %1 >example.txt
echo I live in %2 >>example.txt
echo These are all the parameters passed to batch scripts %* >>example.txt
goto :eof
```

Save it as param.bat and run it as `param.bat param1 param2`.